# How to partition a table in AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm trying to build an application that uses Athena to present Cloudtrail logs.
a simple query takes around 4 mins. it scans around 200 GB.
What I'm looking for is:
(at least one of those fields is used in the query)
[ Event name, Event time, User name, Event source, Resource type, Resource name ]

e.g.

```
SELECT eventid,
    eventname,
    eventsource,
    resources [ 1 ].arn,
    resources [ 1 ].type,
    useridentity.username
FROM My_Table
WHERE useridentity.username = 'username'
    AND eventtime BETWEEN '2022-07-10T13:14' AND '2022-07-27T13:14'
```

How can I optimize the query time? I read [Top 10 Performance Tuning Tips for Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/).
I'm trying to partition the data, but all the articles and examples I found are not much of a help.

Can someone please provide me with a way to partition my data? Or if there's another way to accelerate the performance. (I already have a table, so I want to `ALTER` it, my S3 bucket URI is something like this:
`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/us-east-1/2022/07/25/`

Comment: What is the format of the files? The normal way to improve Amazon Athena performance is to convert the files into compressed Parquet files. Partitioning will make things faster if you use the partitioned element in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Hi, the file format is `.json.gz`

Comment: Then the first performance improvement would be to use `CREATE TABLE AS` to create a new table in Snappy-compressed Parquet format and measure the performance improvement.

Comment: I'm creating the table via the AWS console (in AWS Cloudtrail, there's a button called `Create Athena table`).
It's kinda complicated to create it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you first create a table in Snappy-compressed Parquet format.

You can **create a new table** from the existing table and convert formats.

From [Examples of CTAS queries - Amazon Athena](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html):

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table
WITH (
      format = 'Parquet',
      write_compression = 'SNAPPY',
      external_location ='s3://my-bucket/tables/parquet_table/')
AS SELECT *
FROM old_table;
```

Note that this will create new data files in the location specified. Keep in mind that deleting the table in Amazon Athena will not delete the data in the Amazon S3 bucket.

You can then compare performance using `new_table`.

If you then want to add partitioning, run the same command with `partitioned_by`.

For details, see: [CREATE TABLE AS - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, John, your suggestion did the job! 

Comment: Hey John,
This solution generates another table from my old table and converts it to SNAPPY, great.
let's say I ran this query (to make a new table with SNAPPY format) today at 11:00 am.
so now I have a table that has all the logs till 11:00 am today.
If tomorrow I want to rerun queries, do I need to create a new table again? because the new table that I made before at 11:00 am doesn't have the new records (from 11:00 am yesterday till today).
In other words, it COPIES tables, doesn't MAP tables, right?
If so, is there a way to MAP the new table with the old table?

Comment: More specifically, it copies the files from one location in S3 (as .gz) to another location in S3 (as .snappy). The new table only reads from this second location. You could use the [`INSERT INTO`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/insert-into.html) to select the recent data from `old_table` and insert it into `new_table`. For example `insert into new_table select * from old_table where date > xxx`. This will just copy a subset of data into the new table.

Comment: Hey @John , 
This solution is getting me some trouble, unfortunately. I created a new question about the new problem,[Athena query error HIVE_BAD_DATA: Not valid Parquet file . csv / .metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73267534/athena-query-error-hive-bad-data-not-valid-parquet-file-csv-metadata).
Is there another way to read the data faster? Or keep the Parquet but solve the new problem.

BTW, `partitioned_by` couldn't work for me for my table has more than 20 rows. could you provide me with a detailed solution on how to partition also? (Cloud Trail Logs table)

Comment: I'm confused about what you are doing. Are you using `CREATE TABLE AS` to select data from one table and insert it into a new table? The tables should not be pointing to the output logs that Athena creates. I'm also confused about your statement about `partitioned_by` -- do you mean 20 columns? How is that relevant?

Comment: I'm creating an app that reads data from cloudtrail.
I'm using `CREATE TABLE AS` as you suggested. In the `external_location` field I inserted the URI of my athena output bucket that I also used in my athena settings. ( Query result location ). Is that wrong?

Comment: Do not do that. The output location should be totally empty. The `CREATE TABLE AS` command will create new data files in the location indicated. Keep it separate from the Athena output location.

Comment: That's what I just did and it seems it fixed my problem! Thanks a lot..  