# Athena query error HIVE_BAD_DATA: Not valid Parquet file . csv / .metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, parquet, amazon-athena

I'm creating an app that works with AWS Athena on compressed Parquet (SNAPPY) data.
It works almost fine, however, after every query execution, 2 files get uploaded to the `S3_OUTPUT_BUCKET` of type `csv` and `metadata`. (as it should)
These 2 files break the execution of the next query.
I get the following error:

```
HIVE_BAD_DATA: Not valid Parquet file: s3://MY_OUTPUT_BUCKET/logs/QUERY_NAME/2022/08/07/tables/894a1d10-0c1d-4de1-9e61-13b2b0f79e40.metadata expected magic number: PAR1 got: HP
```

I need to manually delete those files for the next query to work.
Any suggestions on how to make this work?
(I know I cannot exclude those files with a regex etc.. but I don't want to delete the files manually for the app to work)

I read everything about the output files but it didn't help. ( [Working with query results, recent queries, and output files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html#querying-identifying-output-files) )

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not a great idea to use the log output of a query as the input to another query. Instead, use `CREATE TABLE AS` to populate another table.

Answer (score 0):

While setting up Athena for execution, we need to specify where the metadata and csv from the query execution are written into. This needs to be written into a different folder than the table location.

Go to Athena Query Editor > Settings > Manage
and edit Query Result Location to be another S3 bucket than the table or a different folder within the same bucket.